# android studio - data binding error: package ViewController does not exist

Tags: android-studio, binding

Tengo la siguiente estructura en mi proyecto

[image: img]

y el siguiente codigo:

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.databinding.ViewController;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.databinding.R;
import com.example.databinding.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    binding.setClick(this);
}

public void event(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.databinding.ViewController.MainActivity">

<data>
    <variable name="click" type="com.example.databinding.ViewController.MainActivity" />
</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtxt_texto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_aceptar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_aceptar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{()->click.event()}"
        android:text="Aceptar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtxt_texto" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

[image: img]

creo que el error me dice que no se puede encontrar el paquete ViewController pero en realidad esta ahi, este error no me sale cuando muevo la clase `MainActivity.java` fuera del paquete `ViewController`, creo que databinding no puede encontrar clases que se encuentran dentro de otros paquetes, alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se usa `data binding` todos los nombre de los paquetes deben estar en minuscula.

> ViewController

a

> view_controller

se puede usar barra baja.